# What works or books would you recommend to understand Fatalism?

Tags: reference-request

Also, What are some ways to study and measure Fatalism? I'm wondering if sociologists/psychologists/social scientists, in general, have explored the philosophical concept of Fatalism and developed effective empirical tools to measure it.

Comment: Fatalism in the psychological sense is a different concept from fatalism in the philosophical sense, you can read [this article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fatalism/) for the latter (it talks about the difference in the intro)--which are you more interested in?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! Might you have some recommendations for Fatalism in the psychological or even sociological sense (or both)?

Comment: I am afraid this is a wrong side to ask about empirical studies of fatalism (or anything else), this is the purview of empirical sciences. You can try asking on [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).